# error no. 2003 can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (0)

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

Usually inside the parenthesis after the 'localhost' is there should be a (10061) on it but this time it displays (0) i dont know what's this kind of error please help

Comment: Does the MySQL user have the appropriate permissions to access the database? Are the host, user, password and database name all correct (and spelt corretly, in the right case)?

Comment: yes it is correctly labeled username and password set to root